# Can I reset my Wine install?

Tags: windows, software-recommendation, wine, games, mono

I think I borked my Wine install.

Is there a way I can "start fresh", so to speak--completely uninstall everything Wine-related and start over?

Comment: Try deleting your `.wine` folder in your home directory.

Answer (score 7):

Simple to solve without command line or `sudo`.  Just delete the `~/.wine` directory that is in your home folder (were `~` is shorthand for `/home/username` or `/home/$USER`).  You will have to show hidden files to find it.  Wine will automatically rebuild this directory the next time you use it.

While this is the quick and easy way it does leave leftover entries in `~/.local/share/applications`.  Just browse to this folder and delete the unwanted files/directories left from installed Wine apps.  If you don't do this the removed apps will still be listed in your desktop menus even though they are no longer installed.

I use `playonlinux` to help with Wine.  It makes it easier and it allows each program you install to be in it's own little separate virtual Windows drive.  So if you have this problem again you just delete that programs directory instead of all of your Wine stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I have a script with the following entries that I run to remove all wine related in my home directory:

```
rm -Rf $HOME/.wine*
rm -f  $HOME/.local/share/mime/packages/x-wine-e*
rm -f  $HOME/.local/share/mime/application/x-wine-*
rm -f  $HOME/.local/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps/application-x-wine-*
rm -f  $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine-*
rm -f  $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine-*
rm -f  $HOME/.local/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps/7765_*
rm -f  $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine-*
```

Some entries are due to Office installations and may not always apply. As always use `rm -Rf` with extra care.